# location of msfconsole generated executable in Kali linux

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

I am new to security and pen testing. I am using metasploit to generate my payload. I have generated a payload using **generate -t exe -f shell.exe**.
But I cant find the location of the shell.exe anywhere in kali linux. I have tried **find / -name 'shell.exe'**. But still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to give the `-f` flag a fully qualified path

`generate -t exe -f /root/shell.exe`

should drop it in your root directory

You can read more about Generating Payloads on the [Offensive Security Website](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/generating-payloads/)

Here is an example they give

`generate -b '\x00' -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -f /root/msfu/filename.txt`